# "missing authorization clause" while creating schema

Tags: database, oracle, schema

I am trying to create a database schema in Oracle using Enterprise Manager Console as:

```
CREATE SCHEMA SCM AUTHORIZATION SCM
```

but it is giving error as: "missing AUTHORIZATION clause".

Can you please help.

Answer (score 13):

`CREATE SCHEMA` is used to create a whole set of objects in a single statement. It does **not** create "schema" the way other DBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL) use that term.

From [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6014.htm):

> *Use the CREATE SCHEMA statement to create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction*

And the big note at the very beginning:

> *This statement does **not** actually create a schema. Oracle Database automatically creates a schema when you create a user*

(Emphasis mine)

A schema and a user are (more or less) the same thing in Oracle. So most probably you are actually looking for:

```
create user scm identified by scm;
```

Comment: What if it (create user wlp identified by wlp;) throws me a ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name